# firebase - Get the uniqe push ID

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to get the unique ID of push method for this data:

```
{
  "users": {
    "-KKUmYgLYREWCnWeHDfT": {
      "fName": "Peter",
      "ID": "U1EL9SSUQ",
      "username": "peter01"
    },
    "-KKUmYgLYREWCnWeHCvO": {
      "fName": "John",
      "ID": "U1EL5623",
      "username": "john.doe"
    }
  }
}
```

Since name() has been deprecated I tried to use .key, but it returned not the unique ID, but the `users` key instead.

```
ref.child("users").orderByChild("ID").equalTo("U1EL9SSUQ").once("value", function (snapshot) {

    console.log("KEY: " + snapshot.key); // snapshot.key === users

});
```

Comment: When I use `snapshot.val().key` I got `KEY: undefined`

Comment: ohh ... yes ... than this `snapshot.key` should be work i think ... try to log snapshot only

Comment: Then it returns `KEY: users` not `KEY: -KKUmYgLYREWCnWeHDfT`

Comment: log `snapshot` .. and check what value it returns

Comment: its a complete mess: https://jsfiddle.net/zsuqm5px/

Comment: Which version of the Firebase SDK are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you execute a query against the Firebase Database, there will potentially be multiple results. So the snapshot contains a list of those results. Even if there is only a single result, the snapshot will contain a list of one result.

By calling `snapshot.key` you are getting the name of the node on which the query was executed. The deprecated `snapshot.name()` would have done the exact same thing.

To get the key of the matches item, you need to loop over the snapshot's children:

```
ref.child("users")
   .orderByChild("ID")
   .equalTo("U1EL9SSUQ")
   .once("value", function (snapshot) {
    snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
        console.log("KEY: " + child.key);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use .val() to extract a Javascript value from a DataSnapshot. The following should work.

```
ref.child("users").orderByChild("ID").equalTo("U1EL9SSUQ").once("value", function (snapshot) {

    console.log("KEY: " + Object.keys(snapshot.val())[0]);

});
```